# MVC4 using sections to include javascript

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp.net MVC4 application. In my layout page, I have the following code

```
@RenderSection("page-specific", required: false)
```

and In my view which uses the above layout, I have

```
@section page-specific{
  <script src="~/Scripts/page-specific.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

When I run my application, it gives me the following error

Sections cannot be empty.  The "@section" keyword must be followed by a block of markup surrounded by "{}"

But all I want to do is include some page specific styles and javascript. I dont want to include any HTML markup in this particular section. How can I do this while avoiding the empty section error?

Comment: a script tag *IS* markup.  There must be something else going on here.  Are you sure you are looking at the correct code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try naming it `pageSpecific`.  I haven't tried using a hyphen in a section name before, but I have a feeling mvc might not like that.

Comment: That did the trick! Looks like hyphens aren't allowed in section names. I wish the error was more descriptive though. Oh Well, I always learn something new everyday.

Comment: Glad that fixed it.  I was looking all over for the naming requirements for a section, and couldn't find anything.  I'd assume you have to follow the same naming rules as a variable in your C#/VB code (as in not using reserved words or illegal characters).